# Add page number to citation, using biblatex-chicago

Tags: citing, biblatex-chicago

I'm using biblatex-chicago, and I would like to add page number in a citation separated by colon, for example, Smith (2000: 112).

Does anyone know how to do this?

By the way, with biblatex-chicago, `\textcite{}` is used to produce something like, Smith (2000).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}` to your preamble, then use `\textcite[postnote]{key}`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}

\begin{document}
\textcite[112]{bertram}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: thanks so much, it is working!